# how can i use serial port Synchronously in Node js ?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, serial-port

i use serialport module in node js , and execute the code like this, but error occurred.

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    a(i) ; 
}

function a(i){

    port = new serialport(port_name,{

         baudRate:9600 ,

         parser: new serialport.parsers.Readline('\n')
    });

    port.on('open',function(){
         port.write(port_command+'\n');
         data = port.read();
         console.log(i + data);
         port.close();
    });
}
```

but error is occurred ,

"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error Resource temporarily unavailable Cannnot lock port"

"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). "

"DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, 
promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node. js process with 
a non-zero exit code.

I want them to run in order like

a(0) port open , write , read , close

a(1) port open , write , read , close

a(2) port open , write , read , close

a(3) port open , write , read , close

a(4) port open , write , read , close

i think a(0) open, a(1) open so error .. how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return a promise from the function that resolves when the port closes:

```
 function ping(i){
   const port = new serialport(port_name,{
     baudRate:9600 ,
     parser: new serialport.parsers.Readline('\n')
   });

   port.on('open',function(){
     port.write(port_command+'\n');
     data = port.read();
     console.log(i + data);
     port.close();
  });

  return new Promise(resolve => port.on("close", resolve));
 }
```

Now you can achieve your loop as:

```
 (async function loop() {
   for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     await ping(i);
   }
 })();
```